# During installation of the Tor browser a unique asymmetric key pair is created and stored. Is this stored on the HDD/SSD and used repeatedly?

Tags: configuration, security

I would like to know where the unique asymmetric key pair is stored following installation of the Tor browser.  Is it stored in the HDD/SSD and used repeatedly or in RAM and changed for each browsing session?

Comment: I should add that these keys are stored in a 'secure vault' on disk. But what disk. Thinking on 'disk' suggests permanent storage

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is ever "installed" from the Tor Browser that is why it comes in an archive.
Where did this information come from saying that anything is "installed" from decompressing an archive?

Comment: educational text namely the following. 'During installation of the Tor browser the user's browser creates a unique asymmetric key pair and these keys are stored in a secure vault on the user's disk.'

Comment: @StewartBovis do you have links or anything else to the source? quoting false things once more, doesn't make it better.

Comment: Nothing that can be shared unfortunately DJCrashdummy